# Correct routes order in Laravel8 when adding attributes to Product using apiResource?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-routing

What is correct order for apiResource routes.

```
Route::apiResource('product/{product}/product_attribute', ProductAttributeController::class);
Route::apiResource('product', ProductController::class);
```

Or :

```
Route::apiResource('product', ProductController::class);
Route::apiResource('product/{product}/product_attribute', ProductAttributeController::class);
```

In my `ProductAttributeControler` I use:

```
public function store(Product $product, ProductAttributeRequest $request)
```

I added `hasMany(ProductAttribute::class)` to `Product` and `belongsTo(Product::class)` to `ProductAttribute`.

Comment: The first one is correct as it is going to define `product/{something}/product_attribute` and the second one is just normal API REST

Comment: btw, you probably want to use a nested resource to define the nested resource: `Route::apiResource('product.attribute', ...)`  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources

Comment: But its ok to define routes this way?

Answer (score 1):

The correct order is which ever order doesn't result in route conflicts. In your example you could do either and they should not conflict with each other.

I would be inclined to define them using your second option:

```php
Route::apiResource('product', ProductController::class);
Route::apiResource('product/{product}/product_attribute', ProductAttributeController::class);
```

Reasoning being the longer, nested route definition follows the more outer non nested route definition.